# SAS: Sum across variables based on dates between two date variables

Tags: sas

Start_date    |    End_date |monthly_pay_202001 |   monthly_pay_202002  | monthly_pay_202003

12/02/2020  |    01/07/2020      |   200            |       0             |        10
12/05/2021  | 01/05/2022          | 300              |   20             |     20
01/06/2019  | 03/07/2020        |   500               |  5               |    30

To begin with, I have monthly pay variables from 202001-202212

What I want to do is, sum the monthly_pay variables related to the start_date and end_date. For example, if start date is 22/02/2020 - and end_date is 22/06/2021 I would like to sum monthly_pay202002 - monthly_pay202106. If the start_date is before 01/01/2020 then we begin to sum at that start_date until the end_date. If end_date is higher than 31/12/2022 I would like to sum it up until that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create some test data.

```
data have;
infile cards;
input startdate mmddyy10. @12 enddate mmddyy10.;
format startdate enddate date9.;
array pays1(*) monthly_pay_202001-monthly_pay_202012;
array pays2(*) monthly_pay_202101-monthly_pay_202112;
array pays3(*) monthly_pay_202201-monthly_pay_202212;
array pays(*) monthly_pay_202001--monthly_pay_202212;
do i = 1 to 36;
    pays(i) = i;
end;
drop i; 
cards;
12/01/2021 04/07/2022
05/06/2020 08/21/2022
11/15/2019 03/15/2020
11/15/2022 02/15/2023
;
run;
```

The summation across variables can readily be handled with an array. The trick here is how to select the correct range of indices based on the start and end dates. The solution below creates a 2nd array with the monthly first day values that corresponds to the monthly_pay array.

```
data want;
set have;
array pays(*) monthly_pay_202001--monthly_pay_202212;
array months(*) month1-month36;

* populate with first day of each month extracted from var name;
do _i = 1 to 36;
    months(_i) = input(scan(vname(pays(_i)), -1, '_'), yymmn6.);
end;

* ensure the dates are properly bounded;
format strt_dt end_dt date9.;
strt_dt = intnx('month', max(startdate, '1jan2020'd), 0);
end_dt = intnx('month', min(enddate, '31dec2022'd), 0);

* find the index of months array that matches the dates;
strt_indx = whichn(strt_dt, of months(*));
end_indx = whichn(end_dt, of months(*));

* validate the indices accurately reflect the true var;
strt_vname = vname(pays(strt_indx));
end_vname = vname(pays(end_indx));

* sum the monthly pays in the range;
do _i = strt_indx to end_indx;
    sum_pay =sum(sum_pay, pays(_i));
end;

drop _: monthly_pay: month:;
run;
```

Result:

```
startdate   enddate     strt_dt     end_dt      strt_indx   end_indx    strt_vname          end_vname           sum_pay
01DEC2021   07APR2022   01DEC2021   01APR2022   24          28          monthly_pay_202112  monthly_pay_202204  130
06MAY2020   21AUG2022   01MAY2020   01AUG2022   5           32          monthly_pay_202005  monthly_pay_202208  518
15NOV2019   15MAR2020   01JAN2020   01MAR2020   1           3           monthly_pay_202001  monthly_pay_202003  6
15NOV2022   15FEB2023   01NOV2022   01DEC2022   35          36          monthly_pay_202211  monthly_pay_202212  71
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, I'm currently getting an ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 48 column 20 when running this on my dataset. Why does this occur?

Comment: Can't be sure because you don't give enough info to make a solid judgment. My best guess is that your real data set doesn't match the mockup I created and you didn't adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: The code works now :) I had some issues regarding the dates. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First lets convert your listing into an actual dataset. While we are at it we can fix the first record so that the start is BEFORE the end.

```
data have;
  input (Start_date End_date) (:mmddyy.) monthly_pay_202001-monthly_pay_202003;
  format start_date end_date yymmdd10.;
cards;
12/02/2019   01/07/2020   200   0   10
12/05/2021   01/05/2022   300   20   20
01/06/2019   03/07/2020   500   5   30
;
```

To do what you want you just need to create an array and figure out which indexes into the array are the months that overlap with your period.

So find the start and end dates of the overlap period.  Figure out how far away from the start of the array the overlap starts.  Then loop over the period adding up the values from the array.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array amt monthly_pay_202001 -- monthly_pay_202003;
  s=max(start_date,'01JAN2020'd);
  e=min(end_date,'01MAR2020'd);
  offset=intck('month','01JAN2020'd,s);
  total=0;
  do index=0 to intck('month',s,e);
     total=sum(total,amt[index+offset+1]);
  end;
  format s e yymmdd10.;
  *drop s e offset index ;
run;
```

Once you get it working you can drop the extra variables.

Results:
[image]